# SQL Server advanced joining: select records based on a three way user relationship

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a User table that contains UserID and Name.

I have a Likes table that contains UserID1 and UserID2.

When User1 likes User2, their IDs are entered in to the Likes table respectively.

### The Scenario:

User1 likes User2 and User2 likes User1 - mutual relationship.

I want to suggest to User1 all other users that have a mutual relationship with User2 that also like User1 but User1 doesn't like them yet. Liking them will form a three way relationship.

What is the SQL query to return UserIDs for both User2 and User3 along with all other potential 3 way relationships for User1

This is what I have so far, however it is not working 100% as it currently suggests users that don't even like User1 in the first place

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT a.[UserID2] as id_mylike, [user].[id] as id_theylike
FROM dbo.[likes] a 
JOIN dbo.[likes] b ON a.[UserID1] = b.[UserID2] 
JOIN dbo.[user] c ON a.[UserID2] = c.[id] 
JOIN dbo.[user] d ON a.[UserID1] = d.[id] AND a.[UserID2] = b.[UserID1] 
JOIN dbo.[user_likes] f on a.[UserID2] = f.[UserID1] 
JOIN dbo.[user] [user] ON f.[UserID2] = [user].[id] AND [user].[id] IN 
(
    SELECT 
        a.[UserID1] 
    FROM dbo.[likes] a 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[user] c ON a.[UserID1] = c.[id] 
    WHERE a.[UserID2] = @userID 
    AND a.[UserID1] NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT a.[UserID1] 
        FROM dbo.[likes] a 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.[likes] b ON a.[UserID2] = b.[UserID1] 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.[user] c ON a.[UserID1] = c.[id] 
        JOIN dbo.[user] d ON a.[UserID2] = d.[id] AND a.[UserID1] = b.[UserID2] 
        WHERE a.[UserID2] = @userID 
    ) 
)

WHERE a.[UserID1] = @userID
```

Comment: Please share some DDL with us, either on http://www.sqlfiddle.com or in the question itself. And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution (maybe it can be written in a more concise way, but this way is well understandable).

Pratically, I create a new table with three columns (UserA, UserB, UserC), with this meaning:

```
"Tell UserA that his friend UserB has a friend UserC"
```

The query is:

```
SELECT A.UserID1 AS UserA, A.UserID2 AS UserB, B.UserID2 AS UserC
FROM   LikesTable AS A
JOIN   LikesTable AS B
ON     A.UserID2 = B.UserID1 AND UserID1 <> UserID2

UNION

SELECT A.UserID1 AS UserA, A.UserID2 AS UserB, B.UserID1 AS UserC
FROM   LikesTable AS A
JOIN   LikesTable AS B
ON     A.UserID2 = B.UserID2 AND UserID1 <> UserID1

UNION

SELECT A.UserID2 AS UserA, A.UserID1 AS UserB, B.UserID2 AS UserC
FROM   LikesTable AS A
JOIN   LikesTable AS B
ON     A.UserID1 = B.UserID1 AND UserID2 <> UserID2

UNION

SELECT A.UserID2 AS UserA, A.UserID1 AS UserB, B.UserID1 AS UserC
FROM   LikesTable AS A
JOIN   LikesTable AS B
ON     A.UserID1 = B.UserID2 AND UserID2 <> UserID1

ORDER BY UserA, UserB, UserC
```

With the first SELECT, I examine User1, and make a JOIN between his friend User2 and All other User1's of the table that differ from my User1.

Then, I examine User1 whose friends have a friend in User2, and so on.